# SQLite3 3 table join, column doesn't exist?

Tags: python, sqlite

When I execute the query

```
    /* 1st Join: sec_table and wrds */
    SELECT *
    FROM   sec_table
    JOIN   wrds
    ON     sec_table.cik == wrds.cik
    and    file_date between LINKDT and LINKENDDT

    /* 2nd Join:  _______ and sdc */
    JOIN   sdc
    ON     substr(wrds.cusip,0,7) == sdc.cusip_acquiror
    and    sdc.dt_announced between wrds.LINKDT and wrds.LINKENDDT
```

I get the error that `sdc.dt_announced` does not exist although it's column in sdc.

Code to reproduce the error

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

sec_table = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
    """
        page,href,file_name,file_date,company_name,cik
        1,/Document/0001019056-14-000922/,0001019056-14-000922,2014-07-16,"mktg, inc.",0000886475
        1,/Document/0001104659-07-059707/,0001104659-07-059707,2007-08-07,1 800 CONTACTS INC,0001050122
    """)
)
wrds = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
    """
        GVKEY,LINKDT,LINKENDDT,iid,tic,cusip,conm,cik,conml,naics,sic
        1004,1972-04-24,2020-04-22,1,AIR,000361105,AAR CORP,0000001750,AAR Corp,423860.0,5080
        1009,1982-01-18,1996-03-13,1,ABSI,000781104,ABS INDUSTRIES INC,0000313368,ABS Industries Inc,3321.0,3460

    """)
)
sdc = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
    """
        dt_announced,result,cusip_acquiror,cusip_target
        1995-01-01,Completed,31687H,03238Y
        1995-01-01,Completed,N9643A,03882N

    """)
)

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

sec_table.to_sql('sec_table', conn, index=False)
sdc.to_sql('sdc', conn, index=False)
wrds.to_sql('wrds',conn, index=False)

qry = '''
    /* 1st Join: sec_table and wrds */
    SELECT *
    FROM   sec_table
    JOIN   wrds
    ON     sec_table.cik == wrds.cik
    and    file_date between LINKDT and LINKENDDT

    /* 2nd Join:  _______ and sdc */
    JOIN   sdc
    ON     substr(wrds.cusip,0,7) == sdc.cusip_acquiror
    and    sdc.dt_announced between wrds.LINKDT and wrds.LINKENDDT 
'''

pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)
```

`no such column: sdc.dt_announce`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the column names as with `print(sdc.columns)` you will see

```
['        dt_announced', 'result', 'cusip_acquiror', 'cusip_target']
```

Similarly the other tables have leading white space in the first column name.

(NB: when I run this script I get "*UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.*")

One solution would be adding `{DataFrame}.columns = {DataFrame}.columns.str.strip()` for each data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is white-space character while reading data using pandas.
There are multiple ways in which the problem can be solved, for example

1. Cleansing the white-space characters in column name before creating a view/table on it in SQLite

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "")
```

2. if you have SQLite older than 3.25.0 then you can use alias for the columns. Make sure the whitespace is enclosed within ' ' (single quotes)

```
# Identify the columns having whitesapce
cursor = con.cursor()
colInfo = cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info('tableName')")
for r in colInfo:
    print("Columns Names :: " + str(r))

# The above part will print each column name with hidden white-spaces, 
# include the same while aliasing the column name as below.
rsDf = pd.read_sql_query(
    "select ' colNameAlongWithWhiteSpace' as temp  from tableName ", con,
)

print(rsDf.columns)
```

3. If you have SQLite later than 3.25.0, then use alter statement to change the column name.

```
# PySQLite version 
print(sqlite3.version)

# SQLite Version, this value should be greater than 3.25.0
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE <tableName> RENAME COLUMN ' columnWithWhitespace'TO <New ColumnName> ")
```

For more information on ALTER command of SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html